# Should I use Boost Variant for class with different type parameters

Tags: c++, boost

I'm new to C++ and I am not sure the best way to model a class to represent a table of columns; where a column is wrapper around a STL vector with a name (string) and should either be 
 `Column<int>`, `Column<float>` or `Column<std::string>`.

At the moment I have hardcoded it to `Column<int>` but need to support `Column<float>` or `Column<std::string>`.

Should I go down the boost variant route (aka tagged union)?

```
boost::variant<Column<int>*, Column<float>*, Column<std::string>*>
```

Not sure if there's a better solution since it just the type parameter that is different.

I would be grateful to the C++ gods to share their wisdom.

```
template <typename T>
class Column
{
public:
    Column(std::string& name, std::vector<T>& vec) : name(name), vec(vec) {}
    T& at(const size_t i) { return vec[i]; }
private:
    std::string name;
    std::vector<T> vec;
};

class Table
{
public:
    Table(std::string& name) : name{name} {}

    void addColumn(Column<int>* vec) 
    {
        columns.push_back(vec);
    }

    Column<int>*& getColumn(const size_t i)
    {
        return columns[i];
    }
private:
    std::string name;
    std::vector<Column<int>*> columns;
};
```

Comment: Another option is to use a discriminated union, but unions are messy, especially when one if its member has a non-trivial constructor (`string`).

Comment: `boost::variant` sounds like a pretty good solution. On a separate note, you might want to consider replacing the naked `Column` pointers with `std::unique_ptr` (or `boost:scoped_ptr`), since they (if I understand correctly) represent ownership. Also, there is a typo: `getColumn` returns a `Column` of pointers instead of a pointer to `Column`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo; which I've now fixed. Using `std::unique_ptr` is my next thing to do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using Boost.Variant is reasonable for this.  However, you don't need to use pointers at all; instead:

```
boost::variant<Column<int>, Column<float>, Column<std::string>>
```

Comment: Hi John, please could you explain why there's no need to use pointers? It's not obvious to me; I am using pointer because the columns are created from a config file where it's already allocated on the heap.

Comment: Well if you have other constraints in your design maybe you do need pointers.  In particular, if the lifetime of the objects is managed externally, then raw pointers are fine.  But if the lifetime of the objects is managed internally and you are free to modify the design, then you can store vectors of integers and so on directly, and `std::move()` them when needed for efficiency.  In C++11, ask not "When can pointers be avoided?", ask "When are they really required?"

Answer (score 1):

If a variant is appropriate for your use case: *sure*! The template instances are *just* types.

1. You might be able to switch the design to something more like

   ```
   Column<boost::variant<int, float, std::string>>
   ```

   instead though
2. You can generate a variant from a typelist:

   ```
   column_variant<int, float, std::string>
   ```

   In c++11 this is rather trivial:

   **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5ec7e21eb629ca7)</kbd>**

   ```
   template <typename... Ts>
   using make_column_variant = typename boost::make_variant_over<boost::mpl::vector<Column<Ts>...>>::type;
   ```

   Here's a c++03 version of that:

   **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8cab82f63c3cccc7)</kbd>**

   ```
   #include <boost/variant.hpp>
   #include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
   #include <iostream>

   template <typename T> struct Column { 
       T v; 
       Column(T const& v) : v(v) {}
       friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Column<T> const& cv) {
           return os << cv.v;
       }
   };

   /* c++03 helper */
   namespace mpl = boost::mpl;

   template <typename Seq>
   struct make_column_variant
   {
       typedef typename mpl::transform<
           Seq, 
           Column<mpl::_1>,
           mpl::back_inserter<mpl::vector<> > 
       >::type columns;

       typedef typename boost::make_variant_over<columns>::type type;
   };

   int main() {
       make_column_variant<mpl::vector<int, float, std::string> >::type v(std::string("hello world"));
       std::cout << v;
   }
   ```

   This can be considerably shorter in C++11

Comment: Added c++11/c++03 version of the `column_variant` approach

Comment: I've never come across MPL and I need time to understand it. :) The problem with `Column<boost::variant<int, float, std::string>>` is that a column could have a mixture of ints, floats and strings; where I want it to be mutually exclusive.

Comment: @user8090 Note that `[make_]column_variant` is nothing but syntactic sugar, in case this is the part that irked you. I didn't say you need to do either option 1. or 2. :) My direct answer is in the first sentence of the answer!

Comment: @user8090 As a side note I'd add that you seem to be mixing schema typing with the variant handling in this question. They're different responsibilities. To define schemas you could Boost Fusion adapt a struct like `struct PersonRecord{int id;std::string name;}` and generate the matching `Column<>` mappings at compiletime. That way you should not require the variant, outside general code (like query filtering). You wouldn't have to worry about the schema typing because you do that were it belongs. You could independently decide to use `Column<variant<...>>` instead of `variant<Column<T>...>`.

Comment: The real difference between the two is classic trade-offs: whether you want to localize the variant visiting logic to /internal/ to the `Column` type (convenience) or you want to give the compiler maximal chance of optimizing e.g. a case of `std::set<Column<int> >` for a set of ids (performance)

Comment: **Update** I just realized I could simplify the c++11 version to not use `mpl` "at all". See [`make_variant_over`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/make_variant_over.html) for this feature of Boost Variant